# Error: Allow Forecasting is not allowed for this License Type

Tags: chatter, user, error-messages

I am creating a Chatter Free user on a development org and received this error:
 Error: Allow Forecasting is not allowed for this License Type. 
The checkbox is already grayed out so it is not selected in the first place. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a trigger to force forecasting on new users, you'll want to make sure the user license is a salesforce license before setting that to true.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.  I had a trigger from a tutorial I created...thanks